# How to prove that the Newton-Raphson method is convergent in this problem?

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

Use the Newton-Raphson method to find the roots of the function

$f(x) = x^5 - 14.3x^4 + 76.15x^3 - 185.525x^2 + 202.3x - 89.625$, with an initial guess of $x_0 = 1$.

How can we prove the convergence of the iteration $x_{n+1} = x_n - f(x_n)/f'(x_n)$.I have tried several times, but it seems that I cannot find a suitable approach to prove it.

Comment: With what initial point? For a sufficiently large set of initial points you will find all the roots, simply because eventually every set of quadratic convergence will get one initial point inside it. So are there any restrictions? // What statements do you know about the convergence of the Newton method?

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann
with an initial guess of $x_0=1$

Comment: Then the easiest next step is to compute the next 10 points in the sequence. Tabulate function values and the first 2 derivatives (or more). It might be instructive to compare $f(x_n+s_n)$ and $f(x_n+2s_n)$, where $s_n=x_{n+1}-x_n$ is the Newton step.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically [Darboux theorem](http://www.numdam.org/article/NAM_1869_2_8__17_0.pdf).

As long as $$f(x_0) \times f''(x_0) >0$$ the method will converge to the solution with no overshoot. This is you case.

It is simple to find the intervals where $f''(x)$ is positive or negative. Then, select the $x_0$ accordingly.

Just for a stupid illustration, choose $x_0=123$ and run some $30$ iterations. No problem.

Now, choose $x_0=2$ and ...... let me know

Comment: Yes, from $x_0=2$ it needs about 75 iterations to reach the same root that from $x_0=1$ or even from $x_0=2.1$ one can reach in about 13 or 23 iterations.

Comment: @LutzLehmann. With $x_0=2$ the path to solution gives an idea of chaos. Cheers :-)